# Template trick to define a global array in the header

Tags: c++, global-variables, header-files, one-definition-rule

I came across such a trick:

```
// This template utilizes the One Definition Rule to create global arrays in a header.
template<typename unused=void>
struct globals_struct
{
   static const uint8 s_str_serialize_flags[256];
   // ...
};
typedef globals_struct<> globals;

template<typename unused>
const uint8 globals_struct<unused>::s_str_serialize_flags[256] =
{
// ... data here ...
};
   // ... and then the array is accessible as:
   uint8 value = globals::s_str_serialize_flags[index])
```

This code is from Rich Geldreich's [Purple JSON](https://pastebin.com/hnhSTL3h) that I learnt about from Chad Austin's [blog](https://chadaustin.me/2017/05/writing-a-really-really-fast-json-parser/).

Before seeing this code I thought that the only way to have an array in a header-only library is to require the user to `#define` a magic macro in exactly one file (before including the header).

So I like the template-wrapping trick, but I wonder:

- is it a C++ idiom (does it have a name)?
- is it standard-compliant and safe to use?
- is such a template-wrapping the simplest way to have an array in the header?

**Edit:**
I just came across the same trick in a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043566/104453) where it is shown as an alternative to C++17 inline variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the simplest is to wrap it into a function (and `std::array`)

```
using arr256 = std::array<std::uint8_t, 256>;

inline constexpr arr256 s_str_serialize_flags() {
    constexpr arr256 values = {/**/};
    return values;
}
```

or without the `constexpr` constraint:

```
using arr256 = std::uint8_t[256];

inline const arr256& s_str_serialize_flags() {
    static const arr256 values = {/**/};
    return values;
}
```

Comment: `error: ‘values’ declared ‘static’ in ‘constexpr’ function`

Comment: @marcin: Sad that it was not allowed that way :-/ Fixed by alternative (to keep the `constexpr`).