# Why does cppreference define type_traits xxx_v shortcuts as inline constexpr and not just constexpr?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, inline-variable

Why does cppreference define type_traits xxx_v shortcuts as `inline constexpr` and not just `constexpr`?

For example, see [`is_integral_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral):

```
template< class T >
inline constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<T>::value;
```

Is this just a matter of style or is there some difference in behavior? As far as I know `constexpr` variables are implicitly `inline`.

Edit: Looking at the draft of the latest standard, it also uses `inline constexpr`. The question actually applies to the standard, then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043566/2466431

Comment: We made up exactly one `inline` in our type trait variable templates documentation. `is_integral_v` is not that one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[basic.link]/3.2 applies to names of "a non-inline *variable* of non-volatile const-qualified type". A variable template isn't a variable, just like a class template isn't a class, a function template isn't a function, and a cookie cutter isn't a cookie. So that rule doesn't apply to the variable template `is_integral_v` itself.

A variable template *specialization* is a variable, however, so there are some questions about whether that rule gives it internal linkage. This is [core issue 1713](https://wg21.link/CWG1713), the direction of which is that the rule is not applicable.

Core issue 1713, however, wasn't resolved in time for C++17. So LWG decided to simply plaster `inline` all over the variable templates just to be safe, because they don't hurt, either.

Comment: Also in C++20 the wording of [`[basic.link]/3.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3.2) seems to have been changed, now it explicitly says that `const` doesn't imply `inline` on variable templates.

Comment: 1713 has been marked as DUP (which removed lots of info on it..?), but I can't find out what the duplicate is. Maybe [2433](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2433) ?

Comment: @dyp It's not supposed to disappear entirely - I pinged the CWG chair.

Comment: The link to the core issue seems to be broken.

Answer (score 17):

[[dcl.constexpr]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#9)

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const.

[[basic.link]/3.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3.2)

> A name having namespace scope has *internal linkage* if it is the name of
>
> -a **non-inline** variable of non-volatile **const-qualified** type that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage

Without `inline` specifier, `is_integral_v` would have internal linkage. This could be problematic if you compared two pointers to this same variable name taken in different translation unit.

---

Nota Bene: the inline specifier is redundant with constexpr only if the variable is a class static data member.

---

Following an exemple of easy violation of the [one definition rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) that could happen if `is_integral_v` where not inline.

bad_type_trait.h

```
template<class T>
constexpr auto bad_is_integral_v=std::is_integral<T>::value;
```

my_header.h

```
#include "bad_type_trait.h"
void f(const bool& x);

inline void g()
  {
  f(bad_is_integral_v<int>);
  //g ODR use the static variable bad_is_integral_v.
  //"ODR use" approximate definition is: 
  //     the variable is refered by its memory address.
  }
```

source1.cpp

```
#include "my_header.h"
void my_func1(){
   g(); //the definition of g in this translation unit.
   }
```

source2.cpp

```
#include "my_header.h"
void my_func2(){
   g(); //is not the same as the definition of g in this translation unit.
   }
```

In the two translation units, the variable `bad_is_integral_v` is instantiated as separate static variables. The inline function `g()` is defined in these two translation units. Inside the definition of `g()`, the variable `bad_is_integral_v` is ODR used, so the two definitions of `g()` are different, which is a violation of the one definition rule.

Comment: But you know. This raises another interesting question. Why on earth would one take the address of a type trait constant?

Comment: Or maybe nobody is expecting people to take the address. Since `std::xxx<>::value` would be inline on account of being a static data member, the `xxx_v` version is made inline as well, to more closely mirror it. It might just be a matter of consistency.

Comment: @StoryTeller Perhaps to pass it to some generic function template that takes a forwarding reference?

Comment: @T.C. - Fair enough. But was it done in practice pre-C++17? With the original meta-function constants? I'm having trouble envisioning the need.

Comment: @T.C. I too would enjoy learning from an example of where the internal vs. external linkage would make a difference in the scenario you mention.

Comment: @T.C. I have added an example "to be reviewed", thank.

Comment: @Danra I have added an example which show why the `inline` is important

Comment: @StoryTeller I have added which I believe to be a good reason to add the "inline". I ll appreciate your review (confirmation of ODR violation?)

Comment: I'm not convinced that the quote is actually applicable. `is_integral_v` is the name of a variable template. A variable template isn't a variable.

Comment: @T.C. So an instantiate function is not a function and an instantiated class a class??  I think your conception differ from [temp](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#1)

Comment: A variable template (`std::is_integral_v`) isn't a variable. A function template (`std::move`) is not a function. A class template (`std::vector`) is not a class. A *specialization* (whether implicitly instantiated or not) of a variable/function/class template (`std::is_integral_v<int>`, `std::move<std::string>`, `std::vector<double>`) is a variable/function/class.