# Defining global constexpr variables in anonymous namespace the same as making them inline?

Tags: c++, c++17, inline-variable

Following up on [Why does cppreference define type_traits xxx_v shortcuts as inline constexpr and not just constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041618/why-does-cppreference-define-type-traits-xxx-v-shortcuts-as-inline-constexpr-and/48041749?noredirect=1#comment83058095_48041749), if I make my own type trait and want to avoid ODR violations and want it to be compatible with pre-C++17 projects, is putting the xxx_v shortcut in an anonymous namespace the same as explicitly declaring it inline?

For example, taking `all_true` from [Check traits for all variadic template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253399/check-traits-for-all-variadic-template-arguments), with C++17 I can write in my utility header:

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;
template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;
template <bool... v>
inline constexpr bool all_true_v = all_true<v...>::value;
```

Is that the same as writing the following code which is compatible with pre-C++17?

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;
template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;
namespace {
   template <bool... v>
   constexpr bool all_true_v = all_true<v...>::value;
}
```

Comment: The unnamed namespace gives everything within internal linkage... And `all_true_v` has internal linkage anyway for the very same reason @Oliv quoted on your other question (same bullet in C++14). So the two code snippets you presented aren't at all compatible.

Comment: @StoryTeller Of course. My mix up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider

```
    bool const* g_b= &all_true_v<true>;
```

this will have the same address in every translation unit for the `inline constexpr` version, but different adresses for the `namespace {}` version.

Answer (score 2):

You do avoid the ODR violation with the anonymous namespace, as it creates a new separate set of objects in each file where it is included. The advantage of  an `inline` object is that there will only be one in total.

However, if you only use the `constexpr` values as constants, you will not notice much of a difference. And a nice compiler might avoid storing the constants in the data area anyway.

Passing references or pointers around and comparing addresses could make a difference, like Tobi says. But perhaps you can avoid comparing the addresses of two constant values?

Comment: `constexpr` already implies `static` here, so it doesn't really do anything to put them in an unnamed namespace.  That said, you can definitely get ODR problems by defining templates or inline functions that _use_ these multiply-defined constants.  That's why inline variables were added in the first place.