# Any specific reason for variable templates in the standard library be inline?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, variable-templates, inline-variable

C++17 introduced various helper variable templates, e.g.,

```
template< class T, class U >
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;

template< class T >
inline constexpr bool is_aggregate_v = is_aggregate<T>::value;
```

They are all marked `inline`. Since `constexpr` implies internal linkage by default [[ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage)], even without `inline`, the [one definition rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) will not be violated. So I don't see `inline` necessary here. Neither do I see any benefit it brings. So why `inline`?

Comment: Do note I marked it as a duplicate because of the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48041749/817643). Oliv describes how an ODR violation can happen in a hurry.

Comment: @StoryTeller Finally, got to understood the example the second time I read it. What a tricky one!