# What is the difference between inline variables and inline static variables?

Tags: c++, static, c++17, inline-variable

I am a bit confused by the `inline variable` introduced by C++17. What are the differences between `inline variable` and `inline static variable`? Also will this be affected by scope?

```
inline T var_no_scope;
inline static T static_var_no_scope;

namespace scope {
  inline T var_scope;
  inline static T static_var_scope;
}
```

Any explanation will be appreciated!

Comment: non `static` has external linkage and _"...It has the same address in every translation unit..."_ from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: A variable (since C++17) declared as `inline` may be defined in multiple translation units; So long as the definition is identical in every translation unit. It has external linkage.  
A variable declared as both `inline` and `static` would have internal (or 'static') linkage. Exactly like with functions, except with dubious utility (global variables… 'Not dying on that hill).

Answer (score 9):

**At namespace scope:**

`inline static` seems to be equivalent to just `static`.

`inline` on variables only has effect when you define the same variable in several translation units. Since `static` restricts the variable to a single TU, you can't have more than one definition.

**At class scope:**

`inline` can only appear on `static` variables.

It has its normal effect, allowing you to initialize the variable directly in the header. Either:

```
struct A
{
    inline static int a = 42;
};
```

Or:

```
struct A
{
    static int a;
};

inline int A::a = 42;
```

**At function scope:**

`inline` is not allowed.

Comment: Very good explanation. /\

Comment: There is a significant addition of inline static variables as opposed to "bare" static; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502744/1467600

Comment: @DávidTóth I somehow missed your comment. Can you elaborate? The linked answer doesn't seem to talk about `inline static`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sure! simple `static` variables in classes without `inline` need to have an external compilation unit ( i.e. in header-only libraries pre-C++17 code needs workarounds ).  `inline static` variables, as your answer states, make them possible. I think that is something worth mentioning.

Answer (score 7):

For me it becomes more interesting when it is a data members. In `C++17` you can declare your static data members as `inline`. The advantage is that you don't have to allocate space for them in a `source file`. For example:

```
class A
{
// Omitted for brevity
static inline int b = 0;
};
```

So `int A::b;` can be removed from the source file.

Answer (score 1):

`inline` is applicable to variables only with [**static storage duration**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables).

All of the variables in your example have [namespace scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Namespace_scope), giving them static storage duration.  Declaring them `inline` has no net effect if they are `static`.

A variable inside a `class`, `struct` or `union` only has static storage duration if it is declared `static`.  Those varibles must be `static` if they are to be `inline`.

Comment: Declaring them static would give them internal linkage (for non data members), more or less defeating the purpose of declaring them inline.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer about inline variables and why we want to use them can be found [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/sharing-global-constants-across-multiple-files-using-inline-variables/). In short inline variable allows to have multiple definition of a variable (even across multiple files), that will result in one variable in memory. This allow constexpr global variables in header files.

`header.h`

```
namespace constants
{
    inline constexpr double P = 1.11;
}
```

Behavior is undefined when definitions have different values, but this shouldn't be a problem when multiplication of definitions occur only due to header file.

Others have pointed to a nice application in classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct C
{
    static inline constexpr int c = 10;
};
```

And then you can reference this variable anywhere, e.g. with:
`C<int>::c;`

Answer (score 0):

The `inline static variable` can be defined in the class definition and may **specify an initializer**. It does not need an out-of-class definition:

```
struct X
{
    inline static int n = 1;
};
```

**Inline variables** eliminate the main obstacle to packaging C++ code as **header-only libraries**.

If you need to declare global variables that are shared between **compilation units**, declare them as `inline variables` in the header file.

> Also will this be affected by scope?

Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have external linkage and also **names declared without a namespace** for external linkage including in multiple source files must be **inline**.

See this [Example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work) has valuable information about inline variables.

Answer (score 0):

definition from c++ reference: citation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

inline variable is defined as inline static keyword. Hence
inline static vartype yourvariablename // is a inline variable.

Interesting note about inline "A function defined entirely inside a class/struct/union definition, whether it's a member function or a non-member friend function, is implicitly an inline function if it is attached to the global module"(C++ 20)

Ok from personal experience here's why inline static is a really really big thing:

1. If all you need todo is initialize a static variable in a C++ file then you can remove the C++ file and use inline static initialization(but your code will require C++ 17 and up)
2. Initializing static variables in pre C++ 17 classname templates is just overly verbose. You would have to do something like:

template 
class classname
{
static yourtype yourstaticvariable = yourvalue; // and you'll have to initialize it
};

template  yourtype classname::yourstaticvariable = yourvalue;

OR with inline static you can just do:

```
template <class T>
class classname
{
    static yourtype yourstaticvariable = yourvalue; // initialized
}
```

3. You can heavily exploit templates if you use inline static for initializing common things. Consider for instance the singleton where a inline static variable is perfect for tracking the instance and hence can be done in one file where before initializing the static variable would be painful. This becomes even more evident when you have multivariable templates.
4. You need less C++ include files and less lib projects if you exploit inline static for single C++ header. This can heavily trim down files in a big project.

But there some caveats with inline static:

1. You need C++ 17 and up
2. You have to pay attention to issues of putting your initialization in a .h file(which you probably want to do if you initialize with inline static). Although this isn't necessarily a inline static issue but the decision to potentially moving everything to a header could lead to possible issues like namespace collisions, reusing macros or other things if you not careful with your order of inclusion.

But overall it's a fantastic feature. When in doubt initialize with inline static and break the I need a c++ file to initialize a static variable pattern.