# The new feature of C++17 'inline variable' vs 'extern' keyword inherited from C

Tags: c++, inline-variable

What's the difference between the `inline` specifier and the `extern` keyword when applied to a variable?

Comment: Related: [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work)

Answer (score 6):

`extern` says that the variable definition resides in a translation unit elsewhere.

`inline` for global/namespace scope variable means that the definition is provided at the spot. Without `inline` or `const` there will be *multiple symbol definition* linker error.

Comment: inline variable has same address in all translation units same thing for the extern variable.

Comment: @Zeyd Indeed so.