# Is static constexpr variable odr-used?

Tags: c++, c++14, one-definition-rule

Giving below code, is `Foo::FOO1` ODR-used or not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr auto FOO1 = "foo1";
    void bar();
};

void Foo::bar()
{
    const std::map<std::string, int> m = {
        {FOO1, 1},
    };
    for (auto i : m)
    {
        std::cout << i.first << " " << i.second << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the code with `-O1` or above, it is OK, but if compile with `-O0`, I get below error (see [coliru example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/412ddaf42e332d88):

```
undefined reference to `Foo::FOO1'
```

which indicates that it is ODR-used. Which is it?

---

I know the above code is built fine with -O, but in [a real (and more complex) case](https://openpower.xyz/job/openbmc-repository-ci/16600/console):

- The code compiles and links fine with -O2
- The code gets the above `undefined reference` error LinkTimeOptimization (`-O2 -flto`)

So it indicates that both optimizations (`-O`) and LinkTimeOptimization (`-flto`) would affect ODR-use rule? Does this change between C++14 and C++17?

Comment: On compiling with c++17 it works for me.
g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

Comment: hmm... yeah, I should have specified that I am using c++14 for now.

Comment: A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration or non-static member function (until C++14) implies const. A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: Before C++17 it's not considered defined, it's only declared there.  Deduced type makes this complicated. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work

Comment: The wording here is confusing to me. "What is the correct way to ODR-use [...]?" doesn't make sense to me as a question (there is no singular correct way to odr-use something, and that's a strange goal to have) - it seems like the actual question is just if it _is_ odr-used or not. I went ahead and edited this - let me know if you disagree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is [[basic.def.odr]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4):

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is *odr-used* by `ex` **unless** applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression ([expr.prop]).

The first part is obviously satisfied (`FOO1` is `constexpr` so the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does yield a constant expression without invoking non-trivial functions), but is the second?

We're constructing a `map`. The relevant [constructor there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) takes an `initializer_list<value_type>`, which is to say an `initializer_list<pair<const string, int>>`. `pair` has a [bunch of constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), but the one that would be invoked here is:

```
template <class U1, class U2>
constexpr pair(U1&& x, U2&& y); // with U1 = char const*&, U2 = int
```

The important part here is that we're not directly constructing a `string`, we're going through this converting constructor of `pair`, which involves binding a reference to `FOO1`. That's an odr-use. There's no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion here, nor is this a discarded-value expression.

Basically, when you take the address of something, that's an odr-use - it has to have a definition. So you have to add a definition:

```
constexpr char const* Foo::FOO1;
```

Note that, on the other hand, this:

```
std::string s = FOO1;
```

would *not* be an odr-use. Here we're directly invoking a constructor taking a `char const*` parameter, which would be an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

---

In C++17, we got this new sentence in [[dcl.constexpr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-2):

> A function or static data member declared with the constexpr specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable ([dcl.inline]).

This doesn't change anything about odr-use, `FOO1` is still odr-used in your program. But it does make `FOO1` implicitly an inline variable, so you don't have to explicitly add a definition for it. Pretty cool.

---

Note also that just because a program compiles and links does not mean that a variable that lacks a definition was not odr-used.

> So it indicates that both optimizations (-O) and LinkTimeOptimization (-flto) would affect ODR-use rule?

They do not. Optimizations are cool like that.

Comment: So with `-std=c++14` and `-O`, the code compiles fine because it optimizes the code by inline the variable?