# Can initialization order of global variables across TUs be forced with C++17 inline members?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

This is mainly a curiosity-driven question, I do not plan to write such code.
It is a followup from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951527/what-is-unordered-dynamic-initialization-partially-ordered-dynamic-initializati/63953387#63953387) about dynamic initialization order.

From what I presented in the answer, inline static member variables are initialized in the order their classes appear in the source code **if** such order is the same across all translation units(TUs) in which they both appear.

Furthermore, section [[basic.start.dynamic]-3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start#dynamic-3.1) applies both to partially-ordered (other inline static) and ordered variables. That means ordinary global variables in the same TU.

So, given this example:

```cpp
//A.hpp
struct A{
    inline static int a=foo();// Some function with possible side-effects
};

//B.hpp
struct B{
   inline static int b=foo();
};

//X.cpp
int x1 = foo();
#include "A.hpp"
int x2 = foo();
#include "B.hpp"
int x3 = foo();

//Y.cpp
int y1 = foo();
#include "A.hpp"
int y2 = foo();
#include "B.hpp"
int y3 = foo();
```

Are the variables initialized in the following order?

1. `(x1,y1)` in undetermined order,
2. `a`,
3. `(x2,y2)` in undetermined order,
4. `b`,
5. `(x3,y3)` in undetermined order.

Moreover, if there are translation units with only one of the classes, does the rule still apply?

```cpp
//Z.cpp
int z1 = foo(); // Initialized with (x1,y1) ?
#include "A.hpp"
int z2 = foo(); // Initialized with (x2,y2) or anytime later ?
```

In particular, does inclusion of `A::` create a barrier which guarantees that `z2` is initialized after `(x1,y1)`?

Results:

- g++ 10.1.0:
  `x1=1 a=2 x2=3 b=4 x3=5 y1=6 y2=7 y3=8 z1=9 z2=10`
- clang++ 10.0.0:
  `a=1 b=2 x1=3 x2=4 x3=5 y1=6 y2=7 y3=8 z1=9 z2=10`

Both compilers break my assumptions at least for one set of `x,y` variables. What am I missing?
Mainly I am referencing this

> If V and W have ordered initialization and the definition of V is appearance-ordered before the definition of W, or if V has partially-ordered initialization, W does not have unordered initialization, and for every definition E of W there exists a definition D of V such that D is appearance-ordered before E, then

Am I reading this paragraph wrongly? I am not quite sure about the ors and ands.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: "does inclusion of A:: create a barrier which guarantees that z2 is initialized after (x1,y1)?" - No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify your example somewhat to make it easier to understand:

```
// X.cpp
int x1 = foo();
inline int a = foo();
int x2 = foo();

// Y.cpp
int y1 = foo();
inline int a = foo();
int y2 = foo();
```

Your question is whether `x1` is guaranteed to be initialized before `y2` and `y1` is guaranteed to be initialized before `x2`.

The answer is no. As I explained [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57437613/481267) the effect of the partial ordering rules for dynamic initialization is that each translation unit's "instance" of an extern inline variable is notionally treated as a separate variable; the object itself (of which there is only one) is initialized the first time *any* of the corresponding notional variables would be initialized.

For example, one particular ordering would do the entire X translation unit before the Y translation unit. In this case the order of initializations is `x1`, `a`, `x2`, `y1`, (no op because `a` was previously initialized), `y2`. (The compiler could likewise order everything in Y before everything in X, or interleave them.)

The quoted [basic.start.dynamic]/3.1 is from a newer edition of the standard than I was considering in my answer, but the basic logic is the same. Let `V` = `x1` and `W` = `y2`. According to 3.1, `V` will be initialized before `W` if

> `V` and `W` have ordered initialization and the definition of `V` is appearance-ordered before the definition of `W`,

"or"

> `V` has partially-ordered initialization, `W` does not have unordered initialization, and for every definition `E` of `W` there exists a definition `D` of `V` such that `D` is appearance-ordered before `E`

The first condition isn't met because `V` isn't appearance-ordered before `W`. The second condition also isn't met because `V` and `W` each only have one definition, and as I said, they are not appearance-ordered.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for the thorough explanation, I did read it wrong after all.