# Declaring variable in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I would like to know how I can declare a global variable within a namespace.

In general.h I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#pragma once

#ifndef TEST_NAMESPACE
#define TEST_NAMESPACE

namespace general
{
    int n;
}

#endif
```

In my program when I include general.h I have this error :

> Error LNK2005 "int general::n" (? n@general@@3HA) already defined in
>   general.obj

Comment: Well, if you have this ` _GEN_` - don't. Such names are reserved in C++ - you should not be creating them yourself.

Comment: The names you changed are still reserved - any name that starts with an underscore and an uppercase letter is reserved.

Comment: OK I changed the name again but obviously the problem was I should be using the extern keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the keyword `extern` to declare it and define in a `.cpp` file.

Another solution is to use `inline` keyword. `inline` variables are possible since C++17. Learn more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043442/10147399):

> So, in practical terms the (now accepted) proposal allows you to use
>   the inline keyword to define an external linkage const namespace scope
>   variable, or any static class data member, in a header file, so that
>   the multiple definitions that result when that header is included in
>   multiple translation units are OK with the linker – it just chooses
>   one of them.

Also, some of the identifiers you use are reserved. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/10147399) for more one that:

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase
>   letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.