# Why static member can't be defined in headerfile with #pragma once

Tags: c++

Staitc member has to defined in a sourcefile(.cpp) because it will cause error due to duplicate definitions since headerfile(.h) is shared with many sourcefiles. However, if i type '#pragma once
 at the beginning of the heaerfile (or use #ifndef, #endif). it will only run the headerfile once. Then why we still need to initialize static member in a sourcefile?

```
// This is string1.h 
#pragma once
#include <cstring>                 // string.h for some


using std::ostream;
using std::istream;

static int num_strings=1; //why this still gives multiple definiton error even with #proagma once at top?
class String
{
private:
    static int num_strings; // number of objects
}
```

Comment: `#pragama once`/include guards avoid that file is included multiple time in **same** translation unit, not across several translation units.

Comment: Thank you everyone all of ya gave me clear idea!

Comment: Notice that `num_strings` and `String::num_strings` are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of reasoning is wrong. Header guards are to prevent including the header more than once in a single translation unit. Suppose you have two source files:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "theheader.h"

// bar.cpp
#include "theheader.h"
#include "someotherheader.h"
```

Then those two will be compiled seperately, each has the contents of the header. The header guard only prevents to include "theheader.h" twice if for example the other header is

```
// someotherheader.h
#include "theheader.h"
```

To summarize, I allow myself to steal from a comment: "Include guards avoid that file is included multiple time in same translation unit, not across several translation unit"

Answer (score 4):

`#pragma once` does **not** stop a header file from being compiled multiple times.

If you have two .cpp files and each includes a header file, then that header file will be compiled twice. It cannot be any other way because C++ uses *separate compilation* for each .cpp file. So what happens in one compilation cannot affect what happens in another compilation.

What `#pragma once` does is stop a header file being compiled twice during a single compilation. So your won't get errors if you include a header twice in the same .cpp file. This happens more often than you might think. For instance a .cpp file could include two different header files, but each of those header files includes a third common header file. So indirectly the common header file is being included twice in the .cpp file. It's this problem that `#pragma once` is designed to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17 you can get around the ODR violation by making the variable inline:

```
static inline int num_strings=1; 
class String
{
private:
    static inline int num_strings{}; // number of objects
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work) for more information.

Btw, those are two distinct variables. One is `num_strings` and the other is `String::num_strings`.