# Using const variables through multiple header files

Tags: c++

How could I share a constant value that is needed by multiple header files? Or is there some other way around this? What is considered the standard, or is it just preference?

Answer (score 2):

If the variable can be initialized with a constant expression, use

```
inline constexpr type name = value;
```

If not, then

```
inline const type name = value;
```

The `inline` keyword allows for the variable to be defined in multiple translation units and not be a violation of the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: Note that this (applying `inline` to variables) requires C++17 or later.  Before that it could only be used for functions.

Comment: Good overview of various approaches in different C++ versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896763/103167

Comment: And pre-17 a regular header with regular static constants + constexprs(11) would be the way to go.  There are plenty of examples and useful suggestions at  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: constexpr implies inline, you can remove the inline

Comment: @Dani `constexpr` does not imply inline for variables unless it is a static member variable.