# Static variable getting pre initialized with random values

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, static-initialization

Can someone please explain why a member variable (`char m_DBFileName[257]`) of static variable (g_JournalDB) getting initialized with a random value? I expect it to be populated with '\0's.

[image]

More info: g_JournalDB is part of a dynamic library loaded on app startup via

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");
        ...
        System.loadLibrary("mylibraryN");
    }
    @override
    public void onCreate() {...}
    ...
}
```

The screenshot above was taken from a breakpoint in onCreate() of MyApplication where g_JournalDB gets created. I can provide more info if needed.

EDIT: Is it possible that, since I am loading multiple .so files, one ore more .so files have overlapping memory map?

EDIT2: In the class constructor of cAMPDatabase, I am doing `memset(m_DBFileName, 0, sizeof(m_DBFileName))` so I really expect that it is populated with '\0's.

UPDATE1: Later on in the app, I tried to update the `g_JournalDB.m_DBFileName`, I found out that I can no longer access the first 20 indexes. When I did a `strncpy(m_DBFileName, "/data", 256);`, the new value started in index 20. As you can see below, my string "/data" starts at index 20.

[image]

UPDATE2: I was able to determine that the issue is caused by error in memory:

```
09-07 07:57:11.417 309-309/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-07 07:57:11.417 309-309/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'qcom/msm7808/msm7808:5.1.1/WMY57L/ittech01220402:userdebug/release-keys'
09-07 07:57:11.417 309-309/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
09-07 07:57:11.417 309-309/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
09-07 07:57:11.417 309-309/? I/DEBUG: pid: 22437, tid: 22437, name: zapplication.zapp  >>> com.zapplication.zapp <<<
09-07 07:57:11.418 309-309/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x69e793d8
09-07 07:57:11.433 309-309/? I/DEBUG:     r0 0056a27c  r1 69e371ac  r2 0004222c  r3 a0bcab7c
09-07 07:57:11.433 309-309/? I/DEBUG:     r4 ffffffff  r5 a0e29428  r6 be876678  r7 be876618
09-07 07:57:11.433 309-309/? I/DEBUG:     r8 be897ab0  r9 b7a7f1c8  sl be897a40  fp b7a7f1c8
09-07 07:57:11.434 309-309/? I/DEBUG:     ip a09df2f8  sp be876600  lr a094afa9  pc a094afd8  cpsr 300f0030
09-07 07:57:11.434 309-309/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
09-07 07:57:11.434 309-309/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001bfd8  /data/app/com.zapplication.zapp-1/lib/arm/libmylibrary.so (_ZN12cAMPDatabase11CreateTableEPKcP18DB_DATA_DEFINITION+79)
```

UPDATE3: For those who asked, here is the cAMPDatabase class constructor:

```
cAMPDatabase::cAMPDatabase() {
    m_DBHandle = NULL;
    memset(m_DBFileName, 0, sizeof(m_DBFileName));
    memset(m_Tables, 0, sizeof(m_Tables));
    m_TblCount=0;
    this->m_SqlObj = this->NewStmt();
}
```

Here is the header definition (full definition [here](https://gist.github.com/ierosvin/d6ede02883cbf688b84c85734699131c)) for the class:

```
class cAMPDatabase {    
    friend class cAMPSqlStmt;
public:
    cAMPDatabase();
    virtual ~cAMPDatabase();
    // the rest of public variables and functions here ...
protected:  
    char m_DBFileName[257];
    // the rest of protected variables and functions here ...
}
```

Comment: Does your `cAMPdatabase` class have any constructors?

Comment: 'static global' is a contradiction in terms in both C and C++. Clarify.

Comment: @user207421 sorry if my term is incorrect. I am a java developer. anyways, I said it is static global because it was declared as `static cAMPDatabase g_JournalDB;`

Comment: @Botje Yes, it has a constructor. It is in libmylibrary.so.

Comment: If it is `static` in C++ it cannot also be global. Clarify.

Comment: @user207421 I don't know what the proper term is. I am just referring to this variable declaration when i say it is static global: `static cAMPDatabase g_JournalDB;`

Comment: Does the constructor contain code to set the characters to 0? Declaring arrays does not initialise them:  
`#include <cstdio>  int main() { char a[10]; for (auto b:a) printf ("%c\n", b); return 0; }`
just prints some random stuff. (sorry cannot get the line breaks to work)

Comment: hey @alle_meije I updated the question. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Did you attach a debugger to the process to verify that the class constructor can run?

Comment: Yes, the constructor ran when i used the debugger.

Comment: First , it should be `strncpy(m_DBFileName, "/data", 6);` because 6 is the length to copy and second, what happens when you do `strncpy(m_DBFileName+22, "/data", 6);`. At what index does the `"\data"` string now starts ?

Comment: Also I would suggest to set breakpoint right before the `memset` line and right after it. Do the first 16 elements value remains same ?

Comment: @mr.loop yes i put a break point before and after the strncpy. The "/data" starts at index 20 as shown in the screenshot. Also, I don't want to do the +22 as this won't answer the question why the first 20 indexes are no longer available.

Comment: @user1506104 well, I want to see if doing `+22` the string starts at `22` or at `42` or some other number. This would answer a significant part of the problem.

Comment: @user1506104 Also, in first comment I actually asked whether the garbabge characters that occupy first 20 indexes **change OR remain same** before and after `memset`

Comment: Hello @mr.loop. I used +22. This time, the value was copied to index 42, instead of index 20. Regarding your first comment, the garbage characters remain same before and after the memset().

Comment: Strangely it looks as if like your array name is pointing to the 20th index instead of 1st. I would check if `printf("%p %p %p",array,array+20,&array[0])` have same value although I believe the issue can be something related to memory. Also is there anywhere a `#define` or `typedef` statement that includes `m_DBFileName` ?

Comment: How is `m_DBFileName` defined? ` Why not show the C++ code? At least show the definition of `cAMPDatabase` and its constructors.

Comment: @user1506104 Please put the full definition of `cAMPDatabase` in the question and include the implementation of all the constructors if you have more than the one you showed. Is `g_JournalDB` the only `cAMPDatabase` instance?

Comment: @TedLyngmo by the way, i only have one implementation of the constructor as a wrote in the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i added the full definition in this gist gist.github.com/ierosvin/d6ede02883cbf688b84c85734699131c. Regarding other instances of cAMPDatabase, I actually have two instances. But the other one gets instantiated later in the program. Much much later than the timing of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a massive class and I recommend that you initialize all member variables in the one contructor you have.

Example:

```
cAMPDatabase::cAMPDatabase() :
    m_DBHandle{nullptr},
    m_SqlObj{nullptr},    // see note
    m_ErrorCode{0},
    m_DBFileName{},
    m_TableName{},
    m_TableFldDef{},
    m_Tables{},
    m_TblCount{}
{
    m_SqlObj = NewStmt();
}
```

Note: The pointer `m_SqlObj` is created by calling the non-`static` member function `NewStmt()`. For that to make sense, the `cAMPDatabase` instance would have to carry some information but there is nothing in the code that puts anything in the member variables before calling `NewStmt()` - except the `this` pointer.

I therefore assume that the definition of `NewStmt()` looks roughly like this:

```
cAMPSqlStmt* cAMPDatabase::NewStmt(void) {
    return new cAMPSqlStmt(this);
}
```

Unless `cAMPSqlStmt` requires `cAMPDatabase` to be fully initialized, the initialization of `cAMPDatabase` could then be made like this:

```
cAMPDatabase::cAMPDatabase() :
    m_DBHandle{nullptr},
    m_SqlObj{NewStmt()}, // or m_SqlObj{new cAMPSqlStmt(this)}
    m_ErrorCode{0},
    m_DBFileName{},
    m_TableName{},
    m_TableFldDef{},
    m_Tables{},
    m_TblCount{}
{}
```

Comment: we'll try your suggestion. i will revert back. thank you.

Comment: so far it is working. i'll do some more tests and accept your answer, and award the bounty. meanwhile, would you mind sharing book/blog that explains what's happening here? cheers!

Comment: @user1506104 Great! In short, it makes sure that all member variables are properly initialized upon creation. There are however a few classes in your framework that seems to be having _owning_ pointers (like this `cAMPDatabase`) and if it was my project, I'd try to replace all those with existing classes (like `std::string` instead of `char*`), `unique_ptr`s or RAII classes that you write yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **`m_DBFileName` as `std::string`** instead of `char *` or `array`?

And please try to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for static variable initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to know that you were able to find the memory error which eventually became the most probable case.

Although, `std::string` class is preferred in most cases since it is the ***standard and more convinient to handle***.

Also, other possible workaround to this problem if it persisted (non-standard compiler?) may be to explicitly selecting pointer to 0th index by `memset(&m_DBFileName[0], 0, sizeof(m_DBFileName))` and in `strncpy` too rather than simply array name `m_DBFileName` since it is not exacty a pointer to first element but decays into that.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Let's wait for more answers before i give out the bounty. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two possible solutions:

1. use `std::string` -- for obvious reasons, but you may not have that freedom
2. initialise the char array, instead of altering it in the constructor.

There is a difference between

- `static char m_DBFileName[257];` (declaration only, values frozen)
- `static char m_DBFileName[257] = {0,0,...0};` (if you must, but this is declaration + initialisation)

If you don't want to use the last option, you can also do

```
class cAMPDatabase {
   static char m_DBFileName[257];
public:
   cAMPDatabase(): m_DBFileName({0,0,...0}) {};
};
```

If you really need the initialisation to be the same in different compilation units (not sure how that goes with your multiple DLLs) then you may want to use `static inline` instead of just static, or more elegantly, `constexpr`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043566/1793968) and the text below.

Comment: `m_DBFileName` is not `static` though