# Template class static string member not initialized correctly

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, gvariant

I am trying to create a simple wrapper around `glib2.0`'s `GVariant`.

I imagined to have a templated class that would be used to derive a format string of `GVariant`'s type:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Object
{
    static const std::string format_string;
};
```

For now I have hard-coded basic **integral types** and **string** and determined the way to derive **arrays** and **dictionaries** as follows:

```cpp
// Integral types
template <>
const std::string Object<uint8_t>::format_string{"y"};
...

// String
template <>
const std::string Object<std::string>::format_string{"s"};

// Array
template <typename T>
struct Object<std::vector<T>>
{
    static const std::string format_string;
};
template <typename T>
const std::string Object<std::vector<T>>::format_string{
  "a" + Object<T>::format_string};

// Dictionary
template <typename K, typename V>
struct Object<std::map<K, V>>
{
    static const std::string format_string;
};
template <typename K, typename V>
const std::string Object<std::map<K, V>>::format_string{
  "{" + Object<K>::format_string + Object<V>::format_string + "}"};
```

For **tuple** i use the following string deduction method:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::string derive_string()
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts)) {
        return Object<T>::format_string + derive_string<Ts...>();
    } else {
        return Object<T>::format_string;
    }
}

// Tuple
template <typename... Ts>
struct Object<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    static const std::string format_string;
};

template <typename... Ts>
const std::string Object<std::tuple<Ts...>>::format_string{
  "(" + derive_string<Ts...>() + ")"};
```

However, when I try to debug-print the `format_string` member of each `Object` class

```cpp
using IntArray = std::vector<int>;
using IntStrMap = std::map<int, std::string>;
using Int_Double_Bool = std::tuple<int, double, bool>;
using Int_IntStrMap_Bool = std::tuple<int, IntStrMap, bool>;
using Int_IntDoubleMap = std::tuple<int, std::map<int, double>>;

std::cout << "bool type:\n  " << Object<bool>::format_string
          << "\nuint8_t type:\n  " << Object<uint8_t>::format_string
          << "\nint16_t type:\n  " << Object<int16_t>::format_string
          << "\nuint16_t type:\n  " << Object<uint16_t>::format_string
          << "\nint32_t type:\n  " << Object<int32_t>::format_string
          << "\nuint32_t type:\n  " << Object<uint32_t>::format_string
          << "\nint64_t type:\n  " << Object<int64_t>::format_string
          << "\nuint64_t type:\n  " << Object<uint64_t>::format_string
          << "\ndouble type:\n  " << Object<double>::format_string
          << "\nstring type:\n  " << Object<std::string>::format_string
          << "\n[int] type\n  " << Object<IntArray>::format_string
          << "\n{int: str} type\n  " << Object<IntStrMap>::format_string
          << "\n(int, double, bool) type\n  "
          << Object<Int_Double_Bool>::format_string
          << "\n(int, {int: str}, bool) type\n  "
          << Object<Int_IntStrMap_Bool>::format_string
          << "\n(int, {int: double}) type\n  "
          << Object<Int_IntDoubleMap>::format_string;
          << std::endl;
```

I get the following:

```
bool type:
  b
uint8_t type:
  y
int16_t type:
  n
uint16_t type:
  q
int32_t type:
  i
uint32_t type:
  u
int64_t type:
  x
uint64_t type:
  t
double type:
  d
string type:
  s
[int] type
  ai
{int: str} type
  {is}
(int, double, bool) type
  (idb)
(int, {int: str}, bool) type
  (i{is}b)
(int, {int: double}) type
  (i)
```

As it is seen from the last two object printouts, the tuple that includes types that were used somewhere else (`{int: str}`) is derived correctly, while the one that does not (`{int: double}`), are not.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: cppinsights might help to debug template [Demo](https://cppinsights.io/s/3af8f37f).

Comment: You may want to cut out a bit of unnecessary code like the various integer types, but the important bit here is how the code is structured. This might be a case where you forgot [`inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work)

Comment: @Jarod42, even from the demo, I am not able to see, where the problem might be.
I am able to find the `IntDoubleMap::format_string` initialization and seems valid.
@MSalters, `inline` does not seem to do any better. Probably `constexpr` might help but we use GCC9 which does not support it on strings yet.

Comment: There are no `constexpr std::string`. it is just that now, `std::string` might be used in constant expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++17, you might simply do:

```
template <typename... Ts>
const std::string Object<std::tuple<Ts...>>::format_string{
  "(" + (Object<Ts>::format_string + ... + "") + ")"};
```

which solves the issue with gcc
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YvTTWrxaq)

But problems still exists for clang (even for `std::vector<int>`).

I suspect [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof).

Using functions instead of previous/cached results works for both compilers:

```
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<bool>) { return "b"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<uint8_t>) { return "y"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<uint16_t>) { return "n"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<int16_t>) { return "q"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<int32_t>) { return "i"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<uint32_t>) { return "u"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<int64_t>) { return "x"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<uint64_t>) { return "t"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<double>) { return "d"; }
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<std::string>) { return "s"; }

template <typename T>
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<std::vector<T>>)
{
    return "a" + make_string(std::type_identity<T>{});
}

template <typename K, typename V>
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<std::map<K, V>>)
{
    return  "{" + make_string(std::type_identity<K>{})
                + make_string(std::type_identity<V>{}) + "}";
}

template <typename... Ts>
std::string make_string(std::type_identity<std::tuple<Ts...>>)
{
    return  "(" + (make_string(std::type_identity<Ts>{}) + ... + "") + ")";
}

template <typename T>
struct Object
{
    static const std::string format_string;
};

template <typename T>
const std::string Object<T>::format_string = make_string(std::type_identity<T>{});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TGWM1eM14)

Comment: Since `...` is hard to google: this is called a _fold expression_.

Comment: @Jarod42 _Within a single translation unit, the fiasco does not apply because the objects are initialized from top to bottom._

It seems that this could still be the case. If I print `IntDoubleMap` after those prints, the output is the same. If it is printed before, works as expected.

Comment: Issue is template, where are they instantiated? which is the "toppest"?

Comment: Especially as there are several (partial) specializations of both class and static member.

Comment: @Jarod42 What's the difference between using type_identity and not using it? What is type_identity for?

Comment: @ooo0o: `type_identity` serves as tag. Not using it force to have an object (so (default) construct it, which might be not trivial for complex type).

Answer (score 1):

It is because you didn't define the order of initializing `format_string` variables properly.
The following example shows the principle.

```
...
extern string a;
string b1 = a + "b";
string a = "a";
string b2 = a + "b";

int main()
{
    // At this point, b2 will be "ab", but b1 will be "b".
    ...
}
```

In your problem, it's hard to define the order because there are many possible combinations of types. So use static methods instead of static member variables for such problems.

Comment: Not even sure of order with template. (from cppinsight, order seems correct, but it is not according to output).